# Shopping Cart Price Rule Not Applying

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

I have a magento store running 1.9.3.6 and I cannot get a shopping cart price rule to work. Essentially, I want 4 items from a particular category with 3 attributes to be discounted to £10 from full price of £15.96 if 4 of the specific items are added to my cart.

Currently I have:

CONDITIONS:
Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:

Category  is  30
Bottle Size  is  10ml
VG/PG Mix  is  50/50
Quantity in cart  is  4

ACTIONS:
Update prices using the following information
Apply Fixed Amount Discount for whole cart

Discount Amount 5.96
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To (blank)

I have saved the rule.

Now when I add 4 of the specific items which match the above conditions to my cart the amount still shows as £15.96.

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong as this is killing me... any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the rule has been configured properly. Setting the Quantity in cart to 4 means you need to have 4 of the same product in your cart. Also, using "Apply Fixed Amount Discount for whole cart" will only give you a 5.96 discount on the whole cart instead of a 5.96 discount for each of the matched products.

I've updated the cart rule and attached screenshots below. Let me know if this works properly for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend that makes sense - I'll give it a go later and let you know how it faired. Many thanks again :)

Comment: hi Andrew, I tried this but now I cannot add items to the cart to test it. Cart showing as "You have no items in your shopping cart. "...

Comment: Specifically, the cart won't add in Safari, Firefox, IE and Edge. Chrome works on all platforms including mobile... this is really weird

Comment: How can i get the Packing charge from the customer of selected products by using shopping cart pricing rule? @Andrew